# Awk script not working when passed to SSH in a heredoc

Tags: bash, awk

When I run this at the command line it works correctly

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/^AAA/{$3="QQQ"}1' test.txt > newtest.txt`

However when I try and run this in a bash script which SSH's in to a remote server it fails with a syntax error, but I can't see where it fails.  It looks like it's pointing the the FS in the command.

I'm doing the following:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh user@192.168.0.1 /bin/bash << EOF

  echo password | sudo -u root -S awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/^AAA/{$3="QQQ"}1' test.txt  > newtest.txt

EOF
```

The SSH connection works fine, but the awk command fails.
Any ideas how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, that's an interesting command -- you clearly don't need `sudo` to open `newtest.txt` (since the open is done by your shell before `sudo` is run), so all you're escalating privileges for is the read of `test.txt`. But if `test.txt` is so security-sensitive that only root can read it, why would you want to store something derived from it under a less-privileged account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<EOF` in an *unquoted* heredoc. Inside these, all parameter expansions are performed, regardless of any internal quoting.

If you want `$3` to be passed to `awk` without substituting the value for that expansion in the outer shell, you need to use a *quoted* heredoc: `<<'EOF'`, not `<<EOF`.

Comment: Thanks.. This has worked.